# How to use cloud endpoints for media upload?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, endpoints

There is an Media Upload example
https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/guide/media_upload

```
media = MediaFileUpload('pig.png', mimetype='image/png')
response = farm.animals().insert(media_body=media, body={'name': 'Pig'}).execute()
```

Also discovery API describes what flags will be visible in discovery document in order to upload via endpoint

```
"supportsMediaUpload": true,
```

https://developers.google.com/discovery/v1/using?hl=pl#discovery-doc-methods-mediaupload

But there is no example how to use cloud endpoints for media upload
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/endpoints/getstarted/backend/write_api_post

And nothing about supportsMediaUpload in the endpoints library v1.0